# Auto scroll breaks on images load

Tags: reactjs, image, scroll, chat, autoscroll

I have a chat that shows text messages and images with **auto scroll**. I'm using React

So when i load a chat with its messages and images, the auto scroll executes and it scrolls to the bottom of the page. This auto scroll works perfectly only with text messages, but when images are loaded, the scroll stops on some point of the page where a image is.

Here is my auto scroll code:

```
const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)

const scrollToBottom = () => {
   messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
}
    
useEffect(() => {
   scrollToBottom()
}, [chat, messagesSent]);
```

My messages system:

```
<div className="messages__scroll">
   {chat && chat.messages.map((message) => <DisplayMessages message={message} user={user} goToMessage={goToMessage} images={images} scrollToBottom={scrollToBottom}/>  )}
   {messagesSent && messagesSent.map((message) => <DisplayMessages message={message} user={user} goToMessage={goToMessage} images={images} />)}
   <div ref={messagesEndRef}></div>
</div>
```

And my display messages function:

```
const displayMessage = (message) => {
   if(!message.message) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = message.image.title;
      return <img className="messages__image" src={'http://localhost:3001/public/uploads/' + message.image.title} alt="contactImage" />
   }else return <p className="messages__message">{message.message}</p>
}
```

I don't know what to do, if preload all my images (that it would cause performance issues) or what

Comment: Your useEffect hook is probably executed before image is loaded. You can try add an onLoad handler to the image and execute scrollToBottom there.
Generally, auto-scrolling, and keeping scroll at the bottom (also keeping scrollbar scrolled when the user manually scrolls up and new messages arrived) is a bit complicated. It's also difficult to explain how to do it properly in one answer. I advise you to use a ready-to-use library e.g. https://github.com/compulim/react-scroll-to-bottom for scrolling or https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react for chat.

Comment: Ok, i will check it. Thanks!